# How to make a event Listener function return a value? How to track the response from listener function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to write a class which will return me a json object for the given string. I know the syntax for the code below is completely wrong but just tried to do this.

```
package com 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.adobe.*;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    import flash.net.dns.AAAARecord;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class getJson extends MovieClip
    {

        public function getJson(urlString:String):Object
        {
            // constructor code
            var returnObject:Object = new Object();
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            returnObject=urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadingComplete);
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(urlString));
            return returnObject;


        }

        private function loadingcomplete(e:Event):Object
        {
            var jsonObject:Object = new Object();
            jsonObject=JSON.decode(urlString);
            return jsonObject;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This won't work. `addEventListener` doesn't return anything, so `returnObject` is `void`, not an `Object`. What exactly are you trying to do? Events do not work in the way it appears you think they do. They are asynchronous, so there is nothing you can return the data to. If you were to let us know exactly what you are trying to achieve (you are very vague right now), we might be able to point you in the correct direction. At the moment, there is a little we can do to help

Comment: @ Josh Janusch I need to pass url and get around 50 jsons. If I could send and get one by one with feedback, can easily sort according to the need. Now the problem is when I send around 50 json requests to Facebook, have no clue when the listener function will get the json and store in array. If I get a proper feedback from json load listener function, I can process and display result without much delay. Hope you got the issue ...

Comment: And what exactly is "proper feedback"? The `Event.COMPLETE` event *is* the feedback. You can't return anything on an event handler, because there is nothing to return *to*. What you want is simply not possible. However, what you are trying to achieve is exactly what the Event system is meant for.

Comment: @JoshJanusch Fine, as I'm new to developing, getting confused with the listener system. Now completed loading jsons in different order. i.e. I sent requests and received the same in two different orders. I think couldn't figure out the right method to use the Event system for this. Anyways thanks for response ..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  public var urlLoader:URLLoader;
  public  String url;
   public function getJson(urlString:String):Object
    {
        url=urlString;            
        var returnObject:Object = new Object();
        urlLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(urlString));
        returnObject=urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);            
        return returnObject;

    }
   function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
  {
    trace("Progressing");
  }
   function onComplete(e:Event):void
  {
    trace("Fully loaded");      
    urlLoader.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    var jsonObject:Object = new Object();
    jsonObject=JSON.decode(url);
    return jsonObject
  }
```

Comment: No its not working .. I tried similar code and got the following error, Line 21 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type Object.